# How to print multiple QR labels continuously using TSC TTP-244 HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, printing

hello excuse my English:

I am currently making an application to manage inventory PHP - HTML, i am generating the QR code using google api generates charts as image the show that image in HTML format label printing while continuously when printing in the TSC TTP-244 printer only prints one single label me not all.

when printing on a normal printer prints the page breaks css styles

TSC TTP-244 printer is installed via USB on a laptop with Windows 8.1 using the seagull driver 7.3.8

kids thank you very much for your help .. I have several days and I have not been with the solution.

greetings
Clau

Comment: Please define your terms. What is "QR"?

Comment: You can set the css styles for printer separately. I think [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) could help.

Comment: QR Code Labels generated with Google Charts API